# Seekbar and InsetDrawable for progress

Tags: android, xml, seekbar

Hi I try to customize a seekbar.

Here's my Problem:

main.xml

```
   ...
    <SeekBar android:id="@+id/seekBar1" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:thumb="@drawable/seekbarthumb"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/sb2"
                android:minHeight="45dip"
                android:maxHeight="45dip"
            ></SeekBar>
    ...
```

sb2.xml in @drawable

```
<layer-list  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">   
<item android:id="@android:id/background" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/seekbarbg">
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/sb_progress">
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Everything works fine, but the sb_progress was on the wrong position.

So i have 2 solutions. Change the position of the sb_progress or edit sb_progress with Photoshop and add transparent pixels to fix it.

By trying the good way of changing the position something went wrong:

i added some lines to the sb2.xml

```
<layer-list  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">   
<item android:id="@android:id/background" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/seekbarbg">
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress" >
    <inset
    android:drawable="@drawable/sb_progress" 
    android:insetTop="11dip"
    android:insetBottom="11dip"
    android:insetLeft="11dip">
    </inset>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

I added the [inset](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/InsetDrawable.html) element, but the result suxx. the position is correct but the progress isn't animating anymore. The sb_progress.png is always full drawn and don't stop at the thumb.

I need help! Is this a Bug and I need to add transparent Pixels? Isn't

InsetDrawable a subclass of Drawable. Why the seekbar doesn't work anymore with an InsetDrawable.

java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
       ↳    android.graphics.drawable.InsetDrawable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but if anyone finds this through a search engine (like I did) all you need to do is add a 'clip' to the drawable as well as an inset.

```
<item android:id="@android:id/progress" >
    <clip>
    <inset
        android:insetRight="11dp"
        android:insetLeft="11dp">
        <shape>
             <solid android:color="#343434"/>
        </shape>
    </inset>
    </clip>
</item>
```