# Android: Custom SeekBar layerlist not working as expected

Tags: android, seekbar

I have a custom SeekBar:

```
<SeekBar 
   android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/seekbar_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="15px"
    android:paddingBottom="15px"
    android:secondaryProgress="0"
    android:progress="0"
    style="@style/CustomSeekBar"/>
```

with this style:

```
<style name="CustomSeekBar">
    <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/seekbar_width</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/custom_seekbar_progress</item>
    <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/slider_bar_grip</item>
</style>
```

and I have tried two types if layer lists with it. First with nine patch images:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background"           android:drawable="@drawable/slider_bar_track"></item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"    android:drawable="@drawable/slider_bar_track"></item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress"             android:drawable="@drawable/slider_bar_hlt"  ></item>
</layer-list>
```

and secondly with items and gradients:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="4px" android:topLeftRadius="4px" android:topRightRadius="4px" android:bottomRightRadius="4px"/>
            <gradient android:startColor="@color/dark_grey" android:endColor="@color/light_grey" android:angle="-90.0" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="4px" android:topLeftRadius="4px" android:topRightRadius="4px" android:bottomRightRadius="4px"/>
            <gradient android:startColor="@color/dark_grey" android:endColor="@color/light_grey" android:angle="-90.0" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="4px" android:topLeftRadius="4px" android:topRightRadius="4px" android:bottomRightRadius="4px"/>
                <gradient android:startColor="@color/orange" android:endColor="@color/orange" android:centerColor="@color/light_orange" android:angle="90.0" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

This is how it should look like: [image]

This is how it looks like with the images: [image]
The height is too tall (the progress, background and thumb pngs are all 12 pixels high where the background and progress pngs have transparent pixels on the top and bottom to make them the same height) [image] [image] [image] I have these three files in the res folder for all densities with the same size (as I want them to be).
Also the progress always stretches over the entire width of the SeekBar. I have tried to change the order of the layer list but to no avail.

When using the shapes in the layer list it looks like this: [image]
Here, at least, the progress is correct but the height is still too tall.

In this case I need those to be the same height (12px, not dp) for all densities. The screenshots are from a xhdpi device. The height of the progress drawable is the same as the thumb on mdpi devices. How can I make them look the same on all devices and have the progress drawable be smaller than the thumb?

Comment: ok, the height problem could be fixed using ben75s answer and I managed to fix the progress problem using an inset drawable instead of a normal drawable (don't know what that worked, but it did) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514236/seekbar-and-insetdrawable-for-progress)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the strecheable area defined on the left border of your progress and background pngs.

The stretcheable area is currently something like 1 pixel wide exactly at the middle of the left edge. It means that the horizontal center line of your png will be streched. But what you need is "streching the transparent areas".

Do do it :

- remove the black pixel in the middle of the left edge.
- add 2 black pixels on the left edge at about y=3 and y=9 (make sure they are both in the transparent area of the png)